# Website SLA tracking tool

Tags: web-server, web

I am out to find a good SLA tracking tool for monitoring websites. I would to monitor about 1000 plus sites and I'm looking for something that does this job plus provide a good reporting system. I know the question might be too broad but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Pingdom, perhaps?

Comment: Pingdom seems promising but for the amount of websites I'd like to track is quite pricey. Also I would like something that I could self host.